# Adding a Sidebar Icon to my FinderSync extension

Tags: macos, sidebar, findersync

I'm developing a FinderSync extension based on the following documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html

I'm failing to add a sidebar icon.

I've followed the steps: Created the `.iconset` folder and filled it with the requested `PNG`s. Added the folder to my `info.plist` etc.

But I don't see any icon in the sidebar on my monitored folders.

Context menu, toolbar button and badges works fine.

What could I be missing? Is there any limitation that the documentation fails to mention? Anything tricky with step 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently its indeed extremely important to obey Apple's constraints regarding the icons:
they must be

> "monochromatic images that are drawn just using black and
>   transparency"

To my surprise, when a designer gave me `png`s that complied with the mentioned above, everything worked like a charm.

Please comment if you encounter any other difficulty, as the documentation is very lacking.

Comment: Hi @Mugen I want to achieve the same and followed the documentation. But on following the documentation i get a compile time error.

Comment: `Variant named 'template' contains no image resources.`

`Failed to generate ICSN data for variant named 'template'`

`Command /usr/bin/iconutil emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure.`

Comment: We used Photoshop to create the images, they don't have to be icons per se

Comment: For my app in 10.14 and 10.15, [the custom sidebar icon is appearing even without even providing an `.iconset`](https://github.com/knurling/ServiceStation/issues/40). Quite annoying, as I *don't want* the sidebar icons be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions several exceptions where your app icon will not replace the folder's icon:

> The sidebar icons you provide will replace the default folder icons in the Finder’s sidebar for any of the root folders that your extension is monitoring.
>
> This icon does not replace the icon for any folders contained by your monitored folder.
>
> It also does not replace the icon for any system folders that you may be monitoring (for example, Documents, Desktop, Applications, and Downloads).
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html